# Docker SDK with Google Container Registry

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

We want to query `gcr.io` using Python. However, as of this writing, any of the below is not possible:

- Docker SDK: `client.images.list()` only lists local images
- there is no Google Client library for GCR
- images are stored in GCS but as one big list of digests with no metadata. Cannot tell the repo or tags
- `docker registry` in desktop is experimental and not available for querying GCR

The only "hack" is to execute `gcloud container images list (and list-tags) xxx` in a subprocess and parse to extract the info you need.

We could too parse the HTML response from the GCP console (browser) but that would be more work.

Any other idea on how to easily list GCR images in Python ?

And to **Docker** and **Googlers**, any plan on extending your Python library to interact with remote registries, `*.gcr.io` in particular ?

Comment: Why not use the Docker Container Registry :  https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api    ?  It's a standard REST API which you can use with the requests library in python.

Comment: @AdiDembak  was only aware of the engine API. Docker SDK should cover that set too in my mind. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Container Registry implements [the same Docker HTTP API](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/reference/docker-api) as any other Docker registry.

First, get an access token for your account, either with `gcloud auth print-access-token` or [one of these alternatives](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication).

Then, use Docker's ["Listing Repositories"](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-repositories) endpoint of the HTTP API:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> access_token = ...
>>> resp = requests.get('https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog', auth=('_token', access_token))
>>> resp.json()
{
  "repositories": [
    <name>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thx !  For the token, I used `os.popen('gcloud auth print-access-token').read()[:-1]` as `os` was already imported + https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags coz we need the tags.